# WhatsApp API certificate sniff password

Tags: php, whatsapp

i want to send messages through php with the venom whatsappAPI, i followed the suggestions of the API to receive the Whatsapp password of my phone, so i installed MissVenom and started it to sniff my phone traffic. MissVenom gave me a message to install the certificate on my phone on cert.whatsapp.net but the site seems to no longer exist.

Do you have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred with me as well when i was trying to install that certificate. But when i changed my dns in my phone with the one which is provided by missvenom app when you hit start button. It worked and finally i installed it. You must change your DNS and it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

better way to get password for your Whatsapp API is to use [shirioko/WART](https://github.com/shirioko/WART)

shirioko/WART is a small windows application that get your phone number and give you password for PHP WhatsApi